# Table within table styling - blank first column CSS

Tags: css

I've got a table with CSS styling that has a blank (e.g. white background) first column, and a second column with alternating rows. The problem, however, is that I need to insert another table into the table that doesn't apply the same logic and just acts like a normal table.

Every time I try, it gets over-ridden by the styling and the table within the table also appears white

Any ideas?

**HTML:**

```
<table class="ContentTable1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 106.5px;">
                <p><img src="/knowledgeobject/read?id=149&amp;context=image" data-koid="149" />
                </p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 1041px;">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;" width="884">1.</td>
                            <td width="884">Turn alarm off - If already turned off, check to see if anyone else is in the building</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.ContentTable1 td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: We need more code to help you, please insert a snippet of your work.

Comment: Added some more info - let me know if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target just the first column of the parent table, use the [CSS child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) (`>`):

```css
.ContentTable1 > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: I've done so much googling and you answered this in 5 seconds - thank you so much!